# Подсветка ссылок на текущий видимый компонент при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Допустим у меня есть 4 компонента - *main*, *header*, *first*, *second*.

*header* - это плавающий `navbar`, в котором **при прокрутке страницы** переключаются **активные ссылки на компонент** в зависимости от положения пользователя на сайте.

В компоненте *main* я получаю положение пользователя:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <header ></header>
    <first ></first>
    <second ></second>
  </div>
</template> 

<script>
import header from './header.vue'
import first from './first.vue'
import second from './second.vue'

export default {
  name: 'main',
  data () {
     return {
       scrollPosition: null
     }
  },
  components: {
    first,second,header
  },
  methods:{
      updateScroll() {
        this.scrollPosition = window.scrollY
      }
  },
  mounted() {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.updateScroll)
  }
}
</script>
```

Как в компоненте *main* получить положение нужного нам элемента, например, с компонентом *first*:

```html
<template>
  <section ref="first">
      some content
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted: function () {
    this.$refs.first.offsetTop // позиция элемента
  }
}
</script>
```

Как передать из компонента *first* позицию элемента в *main*, чтобы там сравнивать?